Serious mouse problem with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
So i have a weird issue with my mouse. When i move it down it moves normally but when i move it in any other direction its like there's a sensitivity issue and that the sensor is malfunctioning, i have to move the mouse fast so it moves normally. Ive tried switching ports but that didn't work. It only worked when i switched mice but here's the weird thing, when i plug it into my windows laptop it works perfectly fine. But i thing this is some compatibility issue because when i used to use Ubuntu before with the same mouse it worked perfectly fine. But also it may be the new version that's doing this i don't know. Here's some additional info that might be useful: When i was first booting into Ubuntu with my USB I was pressing some keys on my keyboard and moving my mouse, what happened next is that i saw my mouse on the boot which is what i never saw before. My mouse was some kind of + symbol and maybe that's what caused the problem.
My mouse is a Bloody A70

You could try one thing: get your Ubuntu installer USB stick (of the 24.04 version), and boot from it, but instead of installing, choose the "Try Ubuntu without installing" option. That will give you an OS instance that comes from that USB drive, and that is certainly not misconfigured in any ways. Try the behaviour of your mouse on that OS instance and see what it does. Then edit your question and share the findings.

DO NOT repost your question just because you're not getting any responses.  ONLY use one question and track that question.

So do I wait half a year until I get an answer?
